# Advanced (C++) Source Code Re-Formatting with Visual Studio?

Tags: c++, visual-studio, formatting

We would like to be able to reformat C++ blocks/functions of code directly from the Visual Studio IDE, so that developers easily can assure that the *new code* they insert adheres to our formatting guidelines.

I have found the [Artistic Style tool](http://astyle.sourceforge.net/), which pretty much covers the features we'd need. However, it only can work on whole files from the CLI, so it's not very helpful for what we'd want to use it. (Whole file reformatting is certainly never what we want [a].)

Visual Studio (2005) has limited auto-format features, but AFAICS, these are mostly about correct indenting, which is a bit lacking.

So my question is if there are any tools that can do advanced reformatting on a selection from the VS IDE, or maybe if there's a VS IDE plugin making use of AStyle?

Edit: The question linked to recommends a tool - [ProFactor's StyleManager](http://www.profactor.co.uk/stylemanager.php) - are there any other tools like this?

Note [a] : Reformatting whole files or whole project trees is only useful for personal projects or for initial code checkins, IMHO. For a (large) team project, blanket reformatting will mess up the change history of files or lines within files, making it a lot harder to track who's changed what.

Comment: I personnaly run `astyle` periodically on the whole project. This helps maintaining a consistant style across source files.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1663794/visual-studio-unmanaged-c-code-formatter/1663828#1663828

Comment: For your note [a]: I never ran into such issues. The diff mechanism used by most version control system (at least on linux) is tolerant to displacement of lines. And astyle can be configured not to change the time stamps of the files it touches, so that it does not screw the build system. Provided you run astyle before commiting (or before build) each time, there is absolutely no problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found a blog post that describes how to integrate an external code formatter with Visual Studio: [Per-Project Code Formatting in Visual Studio](http://scientificninja.com/blog/per-project-code-formatting-in-visual-studio)

> (...) You can then configure your IDE(s) so
>   that their default formatting commands
>   instead use Uncrustify. In Visual
>   Studio, for example, one can set up an
>   external tool. Assuming uncrustify.cfg
>   is next to the solution file, then the
>   command line
>
> `-c $(SolutionDir)uncrustify.cfg --no-backup "$(ItemPath)"`
>
> will reformat the current source file.
>   You can then assign a keyboard mapping
>   (or reassign the one for
>   Edit.FormatDocument, like me) for
>   quick access.

I haven't tried it, but it seems to boil down to configure your formatter (e.g. AStlye / Uncrustify) as an External Tool in Visual Studio to be able to call it on a source file from the IDE.

Still only per-file, but seems one of the better ideas I found.

Answer (score 1):

Looks there's already an answer for that https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1663794/visual-studio-unmanaged-c-code-formatter

Also. I know in KDevelop and code::blocks they have nice c++ code reformatters and you can customize the style very effectively. I like both .. but code::blocks keeps crashing on me at the moment :(

Comment: I already mentioned this question/answer in a comment-link and a question edit prior to your answer.

Answer (score 0):

The question's a bit old, but the issue isn't.

I use a [VS macro](http://pvdev.wordpress.com/2012/05/23/integrating-uncrustify-into-visual-studio/) to launder C++ code through uncrustify, and trigger it by a keyboard shortcut (ALT+SHIFT+U, my preference). The macro runs uncrustify on the currently active editor document, sends the output to a temp file, and then replaces the current editor's text with uncrustify's output.

Obviously this workflow changes all of the code in the file, but frequent use of the shortcut will keep your code nice and clean. Its conceivable that the macro be triggered automatically when n% of the editor's text changes? I'll leave that to EnvDTE gurus.